# How to compare the price of two sets of business transactions?

Tags: distributions, statistical-power, multivariate-analysis

A business transaction can be defined as a function of 6 independent categorical variables (representing the customer and the product). Sales representatives are allowed to charge whatever price their customers are willing to pay.

Alice and Bob are two sales representatives. They both conduct 100 business transactions in the same time period. For practical reasons, we cannot expect that the 100 transactions from Alice are exactly identical over all 6 variables from the 100 transactions of Bob.

- What is the statistical approach of determining whether Alice was able to charge a higher price than Bob?
- Is the number of observations needed to compare the two populations dependent on the number of variables?
- What is the statistical way of determining whether the "mix" of transactions from Alice are comparable to the ones of Bob?

Comment: There are 6 categorical variables, where are the prices?